# QGIS Points in Polygon Query Not Working

Tags: qgis, polygon, coordinates, query, point-in-polygon

I'm trying to count points within a polygon but it's not working.

I think it has something to do with the co-ordinate system.

The points are from a text file and the line are from a dxf file. I had to set the co-ordinates for both as one was lat long and the other was an old Irish grid co-ordinate system.

When I buffered and dissolve the lines the resulting layer defaulted to the original co-ordinates.

I reset the line file to the correct co-ordinates and ran the query to count points within a polygon. The resulting layer defaulted to its original co-ordinates and all the values were null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For doing a spatial query (what points in polygons is) you better have all layers and project in the same CRS.

I suggest you reproject the layer with lat lon to that old irisch CRS (or visa versa).

You can do that by choosing save as (right-click on the layer in the layerspanel).  There you can define your new crs:

[image]